# Trouble proving divergence theorem

Tags: integration

Suppose we have a cone $z=\sqrt {x^2 +y^2},0\le z \le 1 $ and $\vec F(x,y,z) = <x,y,z>$

Find the flux across the surface.

I will start of with the right hand side of divergence theorem

$div \vec F = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3$

$\int \int \int 3dV$ = $ 3*(volume$ $cone)=\pi$

For left hand side, we have two surface that is the top flat surface, and the curved surface.

$\int \int_{curved} \vec F \cdot \vec n dS = \int \int <x,y,z> \cdot <\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} , \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} ,-1> = \sqrt {x^2+y^2} - z = 0$

$\int \int_{flat} \vec F \cdot \vec n = <x,y,z> \cdot <0,0,1> = \int \int z dA$

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^2 dr d\theta = \frac {2\pi}{3}$

What am I doing wrong?

edit* = found the mistake. forgot the substitute z=1 on the field for the last equation

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the flat calculation:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^2 dr d\theta = \frac {2\pi}{3}$$
In fact
$$\int \int_{flat} \vec F \cdot \vec n = <x,y,z> \cdot <0,0,1> = \int \int z dA$$
But $z$, on the flat, is $=1$. Then we have
$$\int \int 1 dA=\pi$$